# Why use always while loops to fetch mysql results?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop, resultset

The funny thing is that I can't find a good Explanation for this question.
Is there any disadvantage when I don't use a "while-loop" to fetch a mysql result?

Everywhere I see this line of code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   // do something with $row
}
```

I'm not sure that I have ever seen code that used a foreach-loop to fetch mysql results.

So is there anything wrong with other Loops or is the while-loop the only Loop that is easy and simple to use for it?

I guess there is no performance problem for regular uses with while-loops or foreach-loops with 100-1000 resultsets, isn't it?

Comment: Cause with for loop you need to know the number of rows returned with mysql_num_rows and then loop with this number.While loop just ends when all the rows are fetched out.If you dont want to loop you can use mysql_fetch_all

Comment: foreach works on an array (or an iterable object); $result is neither of those things, it's a resource

Comment: Ah ok, because it is a resource. And I can't use a foreach or a for-loop to get the Information from a resource object? Or is a resource not an object just a resource?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is that :
"Foreach" is used when we want to loop through a code for each element in an array.(It handles each element inan array)
"For" is used when we want to loop through a block of code a specified number of times.
"While" : is used to loop through a block of code as long as a special condition is true .

I hope everything is clear for more info you may visit this website : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_loop_types.htm